# Exclude a set of files from htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using the below htaccess rewrite rules to redirect users to the main website if they are accessing files directly and not logged into my website. With this the issue is that when any one share a post to social media the thumbnail picture is not showing in share links (eg:- facebook share).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ https://mywebsite.com/ [NC]
```

The Images which I want to show as a thumbnail for shared links have a common filename format. All ends with -FI.jpg
So is it possible to exclude all those files which ends with -FI.jpg in htaccess rewrite rule? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one `RewriteCond` before `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-FI\.jpg$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, Croises. Thanks a lot. Issue is fixed.